# Probability of cards

Tags: probability

I have this question to answer...

A card is drawn at random from a pack of 52 playing cards. The card is replaced and a second card is drawn. This card is replaced and a third card is drawn.

Calculate the probability of getting at least 2 hearts.

Now, the answer is given to be $\frac{5}{32}$

However, I calculated the answer to being $\frac{9}{64}$ ...

This is since the person would need to draw NNH, NHN, HNN where H is a heart and N is the any other card other than a heart.

Evidently, the N is $\frac{3}{4}$ and the H is $\frac{1}{4}$.

So finding NNH and NHN and HNN is 3 * ($\frac{3}{4} \times\frac{1}{4}\times\frac{1}{4}$)

which is $\frac{9}{64}$?

How is $\frac{5}{32}$ or $\frac{10}{64}$ possible?

Thanks.

Comment: According to your own definition, $NN=$ **exactly $2$ non-hearts**. The question states **at least $2$ hearts**!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add in the possibility getting all 3 Hearts since the problem asks for *at least* 2 hearts. Not *exactly* 2 hearts.  HHH = $\frac{1}{4}\times\frac{1}{4}\times\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{64}$

Adding that to your answer gives you $\frac{10}{64}$